# How to vertically align and horizontally stretch multiple inputs using only bootstrap flex?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

As a learning exercise, I would like to use only [Bootstrap Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/) (or [CSS3 flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)) to vertically left-align and horizontally stretch the input fields. I know about Bootstrap Grid (and [CSS3 grid layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)) but I do not want to use that.

Here's the code (also on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYpOdQ))

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-column">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="flex-fill"><label>Field ABC 1</label></div>
    <div class="flex-fill"><input   type="text" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="flex-fill"><label>Field Long DEF 123 </label></div>
    <div class="flex-fill align-self-stretch"><input type="text" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="flex-fill"><label>Field3</label></div>
    <div class="flex-fill align-self-stretch"><input type="text" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And that looks something like this

---

[image]

---

I've tried align-self-* on the item divs but without any luck. I also tried putting the class directly on the input.

Then I removed the div's around the labels and inputs. Now they stretch horizontally but still no vertical alignment.

And now the result looks like this

---

[image]

---

As a sub-question, I've wrapped each input (and each label) in a div. Is that correct / good / recommended (in terms of how Html / CSS is meant to work technically) or is it overkill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I couldn't solve it using only Bootstrap Flex, but I did it partially with help of CSS3 Flexbox.

I basically removed `.flex-fill` (Bootstrap sets it to have `flex: auto 1 1` which we do not want) and used `flex-basis: <size>` property instead. And I used `justify-content-between` to align inputs to the right.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/vakme/pen/eaygKb)

Code:

```css
input {
  flex-basis: 50%; /* default auto */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-column">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
    <label>Field ABC 1</label>
    <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
    <label>Field Long DEF 123 </label>
    <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
    <label>Field3 </label>
    <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

And about your second question: avoid unnecesary divs, they make your DOM bigger and slow the performance.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.flex-c input{
width:80%;
  height:50px;
}
.flex-c label{
width:18%}
.flex-c{
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-column">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-c">
    <label>Field ABC 1</label>
    <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-c">
        <label>Field Long DEF 123 </label>
    <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-c">
    <label>Field3</label>
    <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

just removed some classes!